# Trouble parsing Divvy bike data with json

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, swift3

Im trying to parse some data from the following link: https://feeds.divvybikes.com/stations/stations.json.

```
       func getData() {

        let url = URL(string:"https://feeds.divvybikes.com/stations/stations.json")

        // Submit a request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data,response,error) in

            // print error if there is one
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                self.alert(messageTitle: "Error", messageM: "An error occured")
                return
            } // end if

            // if there is no error, fetch the json
            if let content = data {
                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers ) as AnyObject

                    if let stationName = json["stationBeanList"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        for station in stationName{
                            if let  lat1 = ["latitude"] as? CGFloat, let long1 = ["longitude"] as? CGFloat{


                                print(lat1,long1)
                            }
                        }


                        }

                }








                catch {
                    print(error)
                    self.alert(messageTitle: "Error", messageM: "An error occured")
                }
            }//end if
    }//end task
        task.resume()

//endqueue   
}
```

I would like to grab the longitude and latitude from the link above and plot them on a mapview embedded in swift but I cant seem to get even the longitude and latitude to print out or store properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

i do call the getData function on load()
 and nothing shows up in the debugger when I run the application.

Comment: Don't include code as a screenshot in your question. Copy it as text into the question and use proper code formatting.

Comment: your right I should have added the code that is my fault

Answer (score 0):

After going through your code what I found is you made a just minor mistake to get lat-long from the call of web service.

if you want to fetch value you need to go according to this after the `for loop` of `stationName`.
Here is sample snippet for more clarification.

```
for station in stationName{
    print(station["latitude"] as! Double)
    print(station["longitude"] as! Double)
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Just tried that and got an error saying : Type(key: String,value: Anyobject) has no subscript memebrs

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are considering the latitude and longitude as String. But its value is not type String.

So `print(lat1,long1)` will never be called.

Solution: Consider it as CGFloat instead of String, it will work I think so

Comment: just tried that It didn't work I just included code instead of picture that is my fault

Answer (score 0):

let url = URL(string:"https://feeds.divvybikes.com/stations/stations.json")

```
        // Submit a request to get the JASON data
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data,response,error) in

            // if there is an error, print the error and do not continue
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                self.alert(messageTitle: "Error", messageM: "An error occured")
                return
            } // end if

            // if there is no error, fetch the json formatted content
            if let content = data {
                do {

                    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: [] ) as AnyObject

                    if let JSON = jsonObject["stationBeanList"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                        for stationInfo in JSON {

                            if let longitude = stationInfo["longitude"] as? Float64, let latitude = stationInfo["latitude"] as? Float64                                    {
                                print(longitude,latitude)



                                    //      self.objects.append(stationInfo(latitude:latitude,longitude:longitude))
                            }//end if
                        }//end if let
                    }//end do


                }//end do
                catch {
                    print(error)
                    self.alert(messageTitle: "Error", messageM: "An error occured")
                }
            }//end if
        }//end task
        task.resume()
    }//endqueue
}
```

Comment: I  had to make it a float64 and created a class to init the longitude and lattitude

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues.

- **The main issue is that the value for `stationBeanList` is an array not a dictionary**.
- `.mutableContainers` is completely useless in Swift, omit the parameter.
- A Swift 3+ JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`, an array is `[[String:Any]]`.
- The unspecified JSON type in Swift 3+ is `Any`, never `AnyObject`.
- A standard JSON floating point value is `Double`.
- Never cast a JSON result to `Any` if the expected type is more specific.

---

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [String: Any] {
    if let stationBeanList = json["stationBeanList"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        for stationInfo in stationBeanList {
            let lat = stationInfo["latitude"] as! Double
            let lng = stationInfo["longitude"] as! Double
            print(lat, lng)
        }
    }
}
```